# Please help in my latex work

Tags: math-mode

I've encountered a problem writing my thesis. I was asked to do it with LaTeX (and I'm new to it) and I'm using Winedt 9.0. I was trying to compile my work but I had problems. I've tried to fixed it but I can't figure it out after a long search so  please help me. I uploaded the main TeX file on a server:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
% THEOREM Environments --------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}




\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
% MATH ------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DeclareMathOperator{\RE}{Re}
\DeclareMathOperator{\IM}{Im}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ess}{ess}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\To}{\longrightarrow}
\newcommand{\h}{\mathcal{H}}
\newcommand{\s}{\mathcal{S}}
\newcommand{\A}{\mathcal{A}}
\newcommand{\J}{\mathcal{J}}
\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}
\newcommand{\W}{\mathcal{W}}
\newcommand{\X}{\mathcal{X}}
\newcommand{\BOP}{\mathbf{B}}
\newcommand{\BH}{\mathbf{B}(\mathcal{H})}
\newcommand{\KH}{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})}
\newcommand{\Real}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Complex}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\Field}{\mathbb{F}}
\newcommand{\RPlus}{\Real^{+}}
\newcommand{\Polar}{\mathcal{P}_{\s}}
\newcommand{\Poly}{\mathcal{P}(E)}
\newcommand{\EssD}{\mathcal{D}}
\newcommand{\Lom}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\States}{\mathcal{T}}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand{\seq}[1]{\left<#1\right>}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\Vert#1\right\Vert}
\newcommand{\essnorm}[1]{\norm{#1}_{\ess}}

\begin{document}
On d\'efinit l \'equation suivant
\begin{equation}
(E)\\x(t)=a(t)+g(t,x(t-\tau))+f(t,x(t))\int^{\infty}_{0}(t-s)^{\alpha-1}u(t,s,x(s)),
\end{equation}
$\alpha\in(0,1)$, $t\in(0,\infty)$.\\

\textbf{But:}

Trouver l'existence et l'unicit\'e d'une solution de $(\mathbf{E})$ dans les espaces vectoriels suivants:
-$PAP(R_{+},R)$\\
-$PAA(R_{+},R)$,\\
 qui est sont des sous espaces de $Bc(R_{+},R)$.

\textbf{Notations}:\\
$Bc(R_{+},R)$:={$f:R_{+}\rightarrow R$, continue et born\'e} est un espace vectorielle muni de la norme uniforme\\
\begin{center}
$\left\|f\right\|_{\infty}:=\sup_{t\in R_{+}}|f(t)|$
\end{center}
 $\big(Bc(R_{+},R),\left\|.\right\|_{\infty}\big)$ est un espace de Banach.\\
\begin{def}
Soit $f$ une fonction dans l'espace $\mathbb{Bc}\big(\mathbb{R}_{+}\times\mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathbb{R})$, $\mathbb{R}\big)$, $f$ est presque p\'eriodique au sens de Bohr pour $t$ uniform\'ement par rapport a $x$ si:\\
Pour tout $\epsilon\succ 0$, il existe $l_{\epsilon}\succ0$ tel que pour tout interval de longueur $l_{\epsilon}\succ0$, il existe $\delta$ telle que :
\begin{equation}
|f(.+\delta,x(.+\delta))-f(.,x(.))|= \sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}_{+}}|f(t+\delta,x(t+\delta))-f(t,x(t))|<\epsilon,
\end{equation}
 pour tout $x\in\mathbb{Bc}\big(\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathbb{R})$
\end{def}
On note par $AP\big(\mathbb{R}_{+}\times\mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R}\big)$ est l'ensemble des fonctions Bohr presque p\`{e}riodique muni de la norme uniforme.\\
\begin{lem}
$AP\big(\mathbb{R}_{+}\times\mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R}\big)$ est un sous espace ferm\'e de $\mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R}_{+}\times \mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R})$.
\end{lem}\\
\begin{def}
Soit$(f_{n})_{n}$ une suite d'elements de $AP\big(\mathbb{R}_{+}\times\mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R}\big)$ telle que $\left\|f_{n}-f\right\|_{\infty}\rightarrow 0$ quand $n\rightarrow \infty$, telle que $f\in \mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathbb{R})$.\\
$\forall \epsilon\succ 0$, il existe $N_{\epsilon}\succ 0$ tel que pour tout $n\geq N_{\epsilon}$, $\left|f_{n}(t,x(t))-f(t,x(t))\right|\prec \frac{\epsilon}{3}$\\
Pour tout $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f-{n}$ est presque p\'eriodique, i.e il existe $l-{\epsilon}\succ 0$tel que pour tout intervalle de long $l-{\epsilon}$ contient un r\'eel $T$:\\
\begin{equation}
\big\left|f_{n}(T+t,x(t+T))-f_{n}(t,x(t))\big\right|\prec\frac{\epsilon}{3}
\end{equation}
pour tout $t\in\mathbb{R}_{+}$.\\
\begin{eqnarray}
\left|f(t+T,x(t+T))-f(t,x(t))\right|&=&\big\left|f(t+T,x(t+T))-f_{n}(t+T,x(t+T))+f_{n}(t+T,x(t+T))-f_{n}(t,x(t))\\
&+&f_{n}(t,x(t))-f(t,x(t))\big\right|\\
&\leq&\left|f(t+T,x(t+T))-f_{n}(t+T,x(t+T))\big\right|+\big\left|f_{n}(t+T,x(t+T))-f_{n}(t,x(t))\big\right|\\
&+&\big\left|f_{n}(t,x(t))-f(t,x(t))\big\right|\
\end{eqnarray}
on applique sup, on obtient\\
\begin{eqnarray}
\sup_{t\in \mathbb{R}}\left|f(t+T,x(t+T))-f(t,x(t))\right|
&\leq&\sup_{t\in \mathbb{R_{+}}}\left|f(t+T,x(t+T))-f_{n}(t+T,x(t+T))\big\right|+\sup_{t\in \mathbb{R_{+}}}_\big\left|f_{n}(t+T,x(t+T))-f_{n}(t,x(t))\big\right|+\sup_{t\in \mathbb{R_{+}}}\big\left|f_{n}(t,x(t))-f(t,x(t))\big\right|\
\end{eqnarray}
ce qui donne que
\begin{equation}
\big|f(.,x(.))-f(.+T,x(.+T))\big|_{\infty}\leq \epsilon
\end{equation}
d'ou le r\`{e}sultat.
\end{def}
\begin{thm}
\begin{equation}
\big(AP(\mathbb{R_{+}}\times \mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R_{+}},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R}),\left\|.\right\|_{\infty}\big) \textf{est un espace de Banach.}
\end{equation}
\end{thm}
\begin{def}
$AP(\mathbb{R_{+}}\times \mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R_{+}},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R})$ est un sous espace ferm\`{e} d'un espace de Banach $Bc(\mathbb{R_{+}}\times \mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R_{+}},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R})$ qui est muni de la norme uniforme, d'ou le r\'esultat.
\end{def}
\begin{lem}
$\mathbf{AP}(\mathbb{R_{+}}\times \mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R_{+}},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R})$ est un espace vectorielle invariant par translation.
\end{lem}
\begin{proposition}
 Si $x\in\mathbf{AP}(\mathbb{R_{+}}\times \mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R_{+}},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R})$
\end{proposition}
\begin{notation}On note par $\mathbf{PAP_{0}}(\mathbb{R_{+}}\times \mathbf{Bc}(\mathbb{R_{+}},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R})$ l'espace des perturbations ergodiques d\`{e}fini par
\begin{equation}
PAP_{0}=\big\left\{g\in Bc(\mathbb{R_{+}}\times \mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R_{+}},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R}),\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^{T}|g(t,x(t))|dt=0\big}
\end{equation}
\end{notation}
\begin{def}
  Soit $f$ une fonction $f(t,x(t)):\mathbb{R}\times\mathbf{Bc}(\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ continue, on dit qu'elle est pseudo presue périodique en $t$ pour tout $x\in\mathbf{Bc}((\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathbb{R})$
  s'il s'ecrit sous la forme suivante:
  $$f=g+\varphi$$
  ou $g\in \mathbf{AP}(\mathbb{R_{+}}\times \mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R_{+}},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R})$ et $\varphi\in\mathbf{PAP_{0}}(\mathbb{R_{+}}\times \mathbf{Bc}(\mathbb{R_{+}},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R})$.\\
  On note par $\mathbf{PAP}\mathbb{R}\times\mathbf{Bc}(\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathbb{R})$ est l'ensemble des fonctionts pseudo presque périodique.
\end{def}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The normal thing to do is to include the file here ("in line"). If the code is not available, it limits the usefulness of this site as a question and answer site. The question contains the problem, which others can see for themselves, and the answer contains the code for the answer for the very same reason.

Comment: The MWE boils down to `\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{def}
  test
\end{def}
\end{document}
`

Comment: There a lot of problems in your LaTeX file! You cannot use `\big\left ... \big\right`, you have to use either `\bigl ...\bigr` or `\left ...\right`. You do not define your environments (`proposition` does not exist, `notation` does not exist, you define `thm` to be Theorem though you write in French, etc.), you have other errors such as `\textf{...}` which does not exist (do you mean `\textbf`?), double subscripts, etc. You really need to learn LaTeX! One possible reference in French is [Une courte (?) introduction à LaTeX](http://hivernal.org/resources/static/computing/doc/lshort-fr.pdf).

Comment: Please write a better title that succinctly describes your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a slighly modified version of your file. There were some typos I corrected. Let me mention that since you use `utf8` input encoding, you can very well  use directly the accented characters on your keyboard.

I loaded the `geometry` package to change the margins which were far too wide and the paper format (the default is letterpaper, which is an American format) and replaced `amsmath` with `mathtools`, a very useful extension of amsmath, to use its `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` to define a `\set` command that provides a correct horizontal spacing and adjustable size of the braces with either the  `star` version or the optional argument `[\big]`, `\Big]`, &c.

Also, you shouldn't use `eqnarray`, which can have  bad horizontal spacing around the alignment point. Use `align` from `amsmath` instead. For unnumbered one line equations use `\[ … \]` in the place of `$$ … $$` (the latter is plain TeX, not LaTeX).

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage[textwidth =14cm,textheight = 21.3cm, marginratio={4:6,5:7}]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
% THEOREM Environments --------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{thm}{Théorème}[subsection]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollaire}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemme}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remarque}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{notation}{Notation}%
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Définition}

\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
% MATH ------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DeclareMathOperator{\RE}{Re}
\DeclareMathOperator{\IM}{Im}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ess}{ess}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\To}{ \longrightarrow }
\newcommand{\h}{\mathcal{H}}
\newcommand{\s}{\mathcal{S}}
\newcommand{\A}{\mathcal{A}}
\newcommand{\J}{\mathcal{J}}
\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}
\newcommand{\W}{\mathcal{W}}
\newcommand{\X}{\mathcal{X}}
\newcommand{\BOP}{\mathbf{B}}
\newcommand{\BH}{\mathbf{B}(\mathcal{H})}
\newcommand{\KH}{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})}
\newcommand{\Real}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Complex}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\Field}{\mathbb{F}}
\newcommand{\RPlus}{\Real^{+}}
\newcommand{\Polar}{\mathcal{P}_{\s}}
\newcommand{\Poly}{\mathcal{P}(E)}
\newcommand{\EssD}{\mathcal{D}}
\newcommand{\Lom}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\States}{\mathcal{T}}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert}
%\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\set}\{\}
\newcommand{\seq}[1]{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\newcommand{\essnorm}[1]{\norm{#1}_{\ess}}
\newcommand{\supnorm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\Vert_{\infty}}

\begin{document}
On définit l’équation suivante :
\begin{equation}
  x(t)=a(t)+g(t,x(t-\tau))+f(t,x(t))\int^{\infty}_{0}(t-s)^{\alpha-1}u(t,s,x(s)), \tag{E}
\end{equation}
$\alpha \in (0,1)$, $t \in (0,\infty)$.\\

\noindent\textbf{But:}\\
Prouver l'existence et l'unicité d'une solution de $(\mathbf{E})$ dans les espaces vectoriels suivants:
\begin{itemize}[label = \textendash]
  \item $PAP(\mathbb R_{+},\mathbb R)$
  \item $PAA(\mathbb R_{+},\mathbb R)$,
\end{itemize}
qui sont des sous-espaces de $Bc(\mathbb R_{+},\mathbb R)$.\medskip

\begin{notation}
  $Bc(\mathbb R_{+},R) \coloneqq \set{f\colon \mathbb R_{+} \rightarrow \mathbb R,\enspace \text{continue et bornée}} $ est un espace vectoriel muni de la norme uniforme
  \[ \supnorm{f} \coloneqq \sup_{t \in \mathbb R_{+}}\abs{f(t)} \]
  $\big(Bc(\mathbb R_{+},\mathbb R),\supnorm{\, \cdot \,}\big)$ est un espace de Banach.
\end{notation}
%
\begin{defn}
  Soit $f$ une fonction dans l'espace $\mathbb{Bc}\big(\mathbb{R}_{+} \times \mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathbb{R})$, $\mathbb{R}\big)$, $f$ est presque périodique au sens de Bohr pour $t$ uniformément par rapport à $x$ si:\\
  Pour tout $\epsilon \succ 0$, il existe $l_{\epsilon}\succ0$ tel que pour tout intervalle de longueur $l_{\epsilon}\succ0$, il existe $\delta$ telle que :
  \begin{equation}
    |f(.+\delta,x(.+\delta))-f(.,x(.))|= \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}}|f(t+\delta,x(t+\delta))-f(t,x(t))|<\epsilon,
  \end{equation}
  pour tout $x \in \mathbb{Bc}\big(\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathbb{R})$
\end{defn}
On note par $AP\big(\mathbb{R}_{+} \times \mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R}\big)$ est l'ensemble des fonctions Bohr presque périodiques muni de la norme uniforme.
%
\begin{lem}
  $AP\big(\mathbb{R}_{+} \times \mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R}\big)$ est un sous-espace fermé de $\mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R}_{+} \times \mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R})$.
\end{lem}
%
\begin{defn}
  Soit$(f_{n})_{n}$ une suite d'éléments de $AP\big(\mathbb{R}_{+} \times \mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R}\big)$ telle que $\left\|f_{n}-f\right\|_{\infty} \rightarrow 0$ quand $n \rightarrow \infty$, telle que $f \in \mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathbb{R})$.\\
  $\forall \epsilon \succ 0$, il existe $N_{\epsilon} \succ 0$ tel que pour tout $n\geq N_{\epsilon}$, $\left|f_{n}(t,x(t))-f(t,x(t))\right| \prec \frac{\epsilon}{3}$\\
  Pour tout $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f-{n}$ est presque périodique, i.e. il existe $l-{\epsilon} \succ 0$tel que pour tout intervalle de long $l-{\epsilon}$ contient un réel $T$:\\
  \begin{equation}
    \bigl|f_{n}(T+t,x(t+T))-f_{n}(t,x(t))\bigr| \prec \frac{\epsilon}{3}
  \end{equation}
  pour tout $t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$.
  \begin{align}
    \left|f(t+T,x(t+T))-f(t,x(t))\right|&=\!\begin{aligned}[t] \bigl|f(t+{}T, x(t+T))-f_{n}(t+T,x(t+T))&\\
    & \mathllap{+f_{n}(t+T,x(t+T)) -f_{n}(t,x(t))}\\
    & \mathllap{+f_{n}(t,x(t))-f(t,x(t))\bigr|}
    \end{aligned}\\[1ex]
      & \leq\!\begin{aligned}[t] \bigl|f(t+T,x(t+T))-f_{n}(t+T,x(t+T))\bigr| & \\\mathllap{+\bigl|f_{n}(t+T,x(t+T))-f_{n}(t,x(t))\bigr|} & \\
    \mathllap{+\bigl|f_{n}(t,x(t))-f(t,x(t))\bigr|}&
    \end{aligned}
  \end{align}
  on applique sup, on obtient
  \begin{flalign}
    \mathllap{\hspace*{1.em}\sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}}}\left|f(t+T,x(t+T))-f(t,x(t))\right|
    & \leq\! \begin{aligned}[t] \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R_{+}}}\bigl|f(t+T,x(t+T))-f_{n}(t+T,x(t+T))\bigr| & \\
    +\sup_{t \in \mathbb{R_{+}}}\bigl|f_{n}(t+T,x(t+T))-f_{n}(t,x(t))\bigr|&\\
    +\sup_{t \in \mathbb{R_{+}}}\bigl|f_{n}(t,x(t))-f(t,x(t))\bigr|&
    \end{aligned}
  \end{flalign}
  ce qui donne que
  \begin{equation}
    \big|f(.,x(.))-f(.+T,x(.+T))\big|_{\infty}\leq \epsilon
  \end{equation}
  d'où le résultat.
\end{defn}
%
\begin{thm} $ \big(AP(\mathbb{R_{+}} \times \mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R_{+}},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R}),\left\|.\right\|_{\infty}\big) $ \textbf{est un espace de Banach.}
\end{thm}
%
\begin{defn}
  $AP(\mathbb{R_{+}} \times \mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R_{+}},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R})$ est un sous-espace fermé d'un espace de Banach $Bc(\mathbb{R_{+}} \times \mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R_{+}},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R})$ qui est muni de la norme uniforme, d'où le résultat.
\end{defn}
%
\begin{lem}
  $\mathbf{AP}(\mathbb{R_{+}} \times \mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R_{+}},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R})$ est un espace vectoriel invariant par translation.
\end{lem}
%
\begin{prop}
  Si $x \in \mathbf{AP}(\mathbb{R_{+}} \times \mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R_{+}},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R})$
\end{prop}
%
\begin{notation}On note par $\mathbf{PAP_{0}}(\mathbb{R_{+}} \times \mathbf{Bc}(\mathbb{R_{+}},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R})$ l'espace des perturbations ergodiques d\`{e}fini par
  \begin{equation}
    PAP_{0}=\set[\bigg]{g \in Bc(\mathbb{R_{+}} \times \mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R_{+}},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R}),\lim_{T \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^{T}|g(t,x(t))|dt=0}
  \end{equation}
\end{notation}
%
\begin{defn}
  Soit $f$ une fonction $f(t,x(t))\colon\mathbb{R} \times \mathbf{Bc}(\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continue. On dit qu'elle est pseudo presque périodique en $t$ pour tout $x \in \mathbf{Bc}((\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathbb{R})$ si elle s'écrit sous la forme suivante:
  \[ f=g+\varphi, \]
  où $g \in \mathbf{AP}(\mathbb{R_{+}} \times \mathbb{Bc}(\mathbb{R_{+}},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R})$ et $\varphi \in \mathbf{PAP_{0}}(\mathbb{R_{+}} \times \mathbf{Bc}(\mathbb{R_{+}},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R})$.\\
  On note par $\mathbf{PAP}\mathbb{R} \times \mathbf{Bc}(\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathbb{R})$ l'ensemble des fonctions pseudo presque périodiques.
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Mico: Sorry, forgot to paste a copy  with the TeX code, instead of what my editor displays :o( It's corrected now.

Answer (score 3):

You're not defining the `def` environment.  Use something like

```
\newtheorem{def}{Definition}
```

As Mark pointed out in the comments, you'll want to change this environment to something other than `def`, though.  Environments work principally by defining two commands, `\<environment>` and `\end<environment>` that are called with `\begin{<environment>}` and `\end{<environment>}`, respectively.  If you use `def` as the environment name, you'll try (and fail) to define `\def`, a TeX primitive.

---

Not that it matters, but you also have

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
```

twice.  Be careful not to fall into the habit of copying and pasting things into a preamble you lug around everywhere. :)

Comment: Also, don't call your Definition environment "def". Try "defn" or "dfn" or something like that. The name "def" is already taken by TeX itself for the \def primitive.

Comment: @Mark You're absolutely right! I didn't even catch that detail.